# How can close all the winning trades in the forex market using the Python language?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, yfinance, forex

I'm writing code in Python, which opens trades according to certain conditions. Sometimes I need to close all profitable trades, which takes a long time if I do it manually, therefore, How can close all the winning trades in the forex market using the Python language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing code in Python, which opens trades according to certain conditions. Sometimes I need to close all profitable trades, which takes a long time if I do it manually, therefore, How can close all the winning trades in the forex market using the Python language?

Answer (score 0):

using asyncio/multiprocessing, opening/requesting/closing trades one by one at a time is a bit of like slightly silly. open your trades as a batch of parallel tasks.

and yeah, they shoul close themselves once they are done with their job